# Mongoexport for Thousands of Collections

Tags: mongodb

There is a database that consists of thousands of collections, and we want to export and import those collections. Also, this will be between different MongoDB versions, so we cannot use mongodump and mongorestore. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How about first installing the same Mongo version to the second location, moving collections there, and then doing a version upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
cmd='db.getSiblingDB("config").collections.find().forEach(x => { print(`--db=${x._id.split(".").shift()} --collection=${x._id.split(".").slice(1).join(".")}`) })'
for ns in $( mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017/..." --eval "${cmd}") ; do
    mongoexport --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/..." ${ns} | mongoimport --uri="mongodb://new_host:27017/..." --numInsertionWorkers=10 ${ns}
done
```

However, first I would try with

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/..." ${ns} | mongorestore --uri="mongodb://new_host:27017/..."
```

because it also creates indexes and privileges. With `mongoexport/mongoimport` you need to create them all manually. I would expect `mongodump/mongorestore` will also work.